# mmenu open submenu branch when on submenu page

Tags: javascript, css, mmenu

I use the mmenu jquery plugin on my wordpress site. The menu has two levels:
- Home
- About
- - Company
- - Team
- Contact

When i click company and then team the team site opens but when i open the mmenu the menu opens with the first level links (home,about) and not the company and team submenu branch.

My code:

```
$("#mobile-nav").mmenu();

var API = $("#my-menu").data( "mmenu" );

$("#navbar-button").click(function() {
    API.open();
});
```

I tried but couldnt figure it out. Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally added some Javascript to so solve this problem:

```
$("#mobile-nav .mm-opened").removeClass("mm-opened");
$("#mobile-nav .current-menu-item").parents(".mm-panel").removeClass("mm-hidden").addClass("mm-opened");
```

Now its working.